# Чему будет соответствовать jQuery объект, если исходный html был изменён не через свойства и методы этого объекта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Такой эксперимент:

1. С помощью jQuery получаем div (или ещё какой-нибудь элемент, не важно); записываем его в значение переменной.
2. Ещё раз делаем тоже самое, записываем в значение другой переменной.
3. Изменяем свойства второго объекта (например, меняем id)

   ```
    $block1 = $('#block1');
    console.log($block1.attr('id'));

    $bock1_copy = $('#block1');
    $bock1_copy.attr('id', 'other_id');
    console.log($block1.attr('id'));
   ```

Вопрос таков: что произойдёт с первым объектом? Он теперь соответствует элементу, которого больше нет?

---

P. S. Долго думал над тем, как сформулировать вопрос. Сейчас Вы видите самое лаконичное, что я придумал, но возможно, это не совсем соответствует содержанию вопроса. Поправьте заголовок, если придумаете более удачную формулировку.

Comment: я уверен уже был такой вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery объект - это не живая коллекция.

При создании его, в нем, в свойстве context, сохраняется соответствующий селектору DOM элемент.

Таким образом для кода в вопросе:

1. есть два объекта jQuery.
2. внутри каждого ссылка на **один и тот же** DOM элемент.
3. изменяется атрибут DOM элемента
4. при запросе значения этого атрибута, вполне логично будет получено его текущее значение.

Таким образом, нет никакого *элемента, которого больше нет*. Есть просто один DOM элемент, и два объекта обертки для него.

```js
$block1 = $('#block1');
console.log($block1.attr('id'));

$bock1_copy = $('#block1');
$bock1_copy.attr('id', 'other_id');
console.log($block1.attr('id'));
```

```css
.content::after {
  content: attr(id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" id="block1"></div>
```

Comment: скопировал из ответа, вопрос которого уже был? ;)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я его не нашел быстро :-) Но я точно помню, что что-то подобное, про живость jQuery уже было :)